# Cocos2D reload white screen error

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game. When we create an EaglView and runwithscene, it works fine for the first time.

```
// TAKE THE SHARED DIRECTOR
director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
// IF THIS IS FIRST OPENING TIME FOR GAME
if (director.openGLView == nil)
{
    // CREATE THE GAME
    if ([CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] == NO)
    {
         [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];
    }
    [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    NSArray* subviews = self.view.subviews;
    for (int i = 0; i < [subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIView* subview = [subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[EAGLView class]])
        {
           [director setOpenGLView:(EAGLView*)subview];
           [director runWithScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];
           break;
        }
    }
}

// IF USER WANTS TO OPEN THIS LEVEL SECOND TIME (OR MORE THAN ONE) 
else
{
      [director startAnimation];
      [director replaceScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];
}
```

I dont know why but when i return to menu and try to reload the game, a white screen appears, (i put breakpoint and observed that the game code is being worked and initialized), but only white screen appears.

I appreciate for help. Thanks

Comment: Did you have any luck fixing this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: When you say reload the game, do you mean closing out of the app? If you close out of the app and try and reopen in while in the simulator, you will run into these problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be it's root view controller Background view.For Ex,Window is a root view controller and it's background is white. you put your scene and view on to that.when you go back your root view controller is display.so, set background of your Root view controller (Like-Window).